# Variable template in template class - unexpected error (possible bug?)

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, auto, variable-templates

Having:

```
struct Value
{
    template<class T>
    static constexpr T value{0};
};
```

---

**(0)**
[ideone](http://ideone.com/AUo86z)

```
template<typename TValue>
struct Something
{
    void x()
    {
        static_assert(TValue::template value<int> == 0, "");
    }
};

int main() { Something<Value>{}.x(); return 0; }
```

- Does not compile with clang++ 3.6.

  > error: cannot refer to variable template 'value' without a template argument list
- Does not compile with g++ 5.2.

  > error: ‘template constexpr const T Value::value’ is not a function template

---

**(1)**
[ideone](http://ideone.com/efJbP2)

Compiles with both clang++ and g++.

```
struct Something
{
    void x()
    {
        static_assert(Value::template value<int> == 0, "");
    }
};

int main() { Something{}.x(); return 0; }
```

---

Why does **(0)** fail to compile?

It seems that the issue occurs if the *variable template* is accessed through a template parameter (in this case, `TValue`). Defining a type alias for `TValue` or using the `typename` keyword does not fix the issue.

What's going on here?

Comment: What is `template<class T>
    static constexpr T value{0};` supposed to do? Is it something new? How is that called?

Comment: @BЈовић, It is called *variable template*, added in C++14. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14#Variable_templates) (wiki) and [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template) (cppreference)

Comment: (0) fails for me on clang 3.6, with "cannot refer to variable template '`value`' without a template argument list"

Comment: I edited the original question: `auto` was not part of the issue - for some reason ClangComplete (Sublime Text plugin) did not display errors when `int` was used in place of `auto`. The issue regards the fact that `TValue` is a template parameter of `Something`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is definitely a gcc and clang bug in their treatment of variable templates as dependent names. I submitted [gcc 67248](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67248) and [clang 24473](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=24473).

As a workaround for now, both compilers support the old way of doing variable templates, namely if you added:

```
struct Value
{
    template<class T>
    static constexpr T value = 0;

    template <typename T>
    struct variable_template_ish {
        static constexpr T value = Value::value<T>;
    };
};
```

then the following compiles:

```
template<typename TValue>
struct Something
{
    void foo() {
        static_assert(TValue::template variable_template_ish<int>::value == 0, "");
    }
};

int main() { 
    Something<Value>{}.foo();
}
```

Comment: I *knew* it was a bug. Strange that both gcc and clang got it wrong, though. The workaround I used was actually defining `static constexpr` functions that wrapped the variables.

Answer (score 0):

I've had some headaches before when creating template class header files in c++.

Make sure you implementation of `static constexpr T value{0};` is in the same header file as the declaration.

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer

Comment: This should be included as a comment not an answer

Comment: Thank you. It was my first response... apologies :-)